# Getting rid of .DS_Store file while creating a corpus from scratch

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I am extremely new to Python and I need to create a corpus from scratch. I am having a problem with the .DS_Store file. I tried erasing it manually, erasing it with Terminal or erasing it with Python and nothing worked. I am not able to do my NLP computations while .DS_Store exists. This is my code:

```
import nltk
import random
nltk.download('cmudict')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.corpus import cmudict
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
from nltk import word_tokenize
import os
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader

corpusdir = '/Users/username/nltk_data/corpusfilename'
corp = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusdir, '.*')
corp.fileids() # gives me 6 fileids, 5 existing and one .DS_Store

corp.sents() # error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 161: invalid 
continuation byte
```

I am using a Mac and it is recommended to use an if statement so that corpus can only read .txt but not .DS_Store. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: The main goal here is to point `PlaintextCorpusReader` to the right files, in this respect you should accept the answer given by @ygorg and rephrase your question and its title to help future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store):

> In the Apple macOS operating system, .DS_Store is a file that stores custom attributes of its containing folder, such as the position of icons or the choice of a background image.

So there will likely always be a `.DS_Store`, anywhere.

In this line : `corp = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusdir, '.*')` you choose which files will be in the corpus.

The second parameter `'.*'` is a regular expression that selects which files will be used. According to [the doc](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.html#PlaintextCorpusReader) this parameter can be "A list or regexp specifying the fileids in this corpus.".

So in your case you can change `'.*'` that matches everything to `'.*\.txt'` to match any characters and a '.' and 'txt'. Or if you know the name of every file you need you can use a list of file names `['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']`.

Answer (score -2):

```html
find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete
```

The above script will do the trick in removing the files from your directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I copied this to Jupyter notebook and ran it but it gives me a syntax error (invalid syntax). Should I run this in Terminal or in Python?

Comment: You should run this in terminal.